# Melhor forma de retornar dados inseridos por um select de constantes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Tenho um modelo `Usuario` e para ele tenho duas constantes que definem um tipo para ele. Para passar essa informação para um `select` tenho um método tipos que retorna um `Array`. Ex:

```
#models/Usuario.rb
class Usuario < ActiveRecord::Base
    def tipos
        [["Tipo 1",1], ["Tipo 2",2]]
    end
end

#views/usuarios/_form.html.erb
        <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :tipo %><br>
            <%= f.select :tipo,@usuario.tipos, :class=>"form-control" %>
        </div>
```

Sendo assim, em meu `index` serão exibidos 1 e 2 respectivamente ao seus tipos. Obviamente **gostaria que fosse exibido Tipo 1  e Tipo 2 em cada caso**.

Atualmente como estou fazendo assim:

```
#models/Usuario.rb
class Usuario < ActiveRecord::Base
    def tipos
        [["Tipo 1",1], ["Tipo 2",2]]
    end

    def tipo_tos
        #inverte chave, valor, converte em Hash, pega o nome do tipo
        Hash[tipos.map { |t| [t[1],t[0]]  }][self.tipo]
    end

end
```

Algum maneira mais eficiente de fazer isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em vez de transformar a lista em um hash você pode fazer a busca diretamente usando o método `find`. Assim:

```
def tipo_tos
    tipos.find {|t| t[1] == tipo}[0]
end
```

Mas talvez o mais interessante seja guardar os tipos como um hash desde o começo. Assim:

```
class Usuario < ActiveRecord::Base
    TABELA_TIPOS = {
        1 => "Tipo 1",
        2 => "Tipo 2"
    }
    TIPOS = TABELA_TIPOS.to_a.map(&:reverse)

    def self.tipos
        TIPOS
    end

    def tipo_tos
        TABELA_TIPOS[tipo] # Eficiente!
    end
end
```

Com isso você pode chamar `Usuario.tipos` para obter a lista (transformei em um método de classe, já que não usa a instância).

Comment: Muito bom @Guilherme !